# Asymptotic behavior of the coefficients of expansion of $\sqrt{1-4a(1-a) \cdot x+(2a-1)\sqrt{1-4a(1-a) \cdot x^2}}$ as a power series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, laplace-transform, generating-functions, contour-integration

Consider the following generating function of some sequence $(f_n)_n$
$$
G(f_n;x) = \sqrt{1-4a(1-a) \cdot x+(2a-1)\sqrt{1-4a(1-a) \cdot x^2}}
$$
for $0\leq a\leq1/2$. How can I deduce the asymptotic formula of the coefficients corresponding to the above generating function?

The first five coefficients of the expansion around zero are:
\begin{align}
&x^0:\ \sqrt{2a}\\
&x^1:\ -\sqrt{2}(1-a)\sqrt{a}\\
&x^2:\ -\sqrt{2}(1-a)^2\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{2}(1-a)\sqrt{a}(2a-1)\\
&x^3:\ -3\sqrt{2}(1-a)^3\sqrt{a}-3\sqrt{2}(1-a)^2\sqrt{a}(2a-1)\\
&x^4:\ -15\sqrt{2}(1-a)^4\sqrt{a}-18\sqrt{2}(1-a)^3\sqrt{a}(2a-1)-12\sqrt{2}(1-a)^2a^{3/2}(2a-1)\\
&\ \ \ \  \ \ \ \;\ -3\sqrt{2}(1-a)^2\sqrt{a}(2a-1)^2\\
&x^5:\ -105\sqrt{2}(1 - a)^5\sqrt{a} - 
 150 \sqrt{2} (1 - a)^4 \sqrt{a} (2a-1) - 
 60 \sqrt{2} (1 - a)^3 a^{3/2} (2a-1) - 
 45 \sqrt{2} (1 - a)^3 \sqrt{a} (2a-1)^2
\end{align}

Comment: What do you have for the first few coefficients? Did you try the [OEIS](http://oeis.org)?

Comment: I tired to find the first few coefficients but couldn't find any simple pattern.

Comment: What are the first few coefficients?

Comment: @Somos I've added the first five coefficients around zero.

Comment: Okay, I was afraid of that. If $x=0$ then the expression is just $\sqrt(2a)$ so your $x^0$ term is wrong. Please redo your computations and/or correct your formula.

Comment: @Somos Right, this was a typo. Sorry about that (I also double checked all the computation using Wolfarm Mathematica).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64070/discussion-between-somos-and-j-john).

Comment: Using Mathematica I verified that for $0\leq a\leq \dfrac{1}{2}$ the sequences tend to $0$. Furthermore if you write down the terms like you did you have a MacLaurin expansion $G(a,x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }f_n(a)\,x^n$ and if you plug $x=1$ in each monomial of the sum you get the terms of the sequence. If you substitute $x=1$ directly in $G$ you get $\sqrt{2} (1-2 a)\quad$  This is the value of the sum of the $f_n(a)$ but I can't figure out the actual meaning of this in relation with the asymptotic behaviour

Comment: Yes, they will indeed tend to zero, but actually I need to estimate the decay rate.

Comment: There are formulas connecting the Maclaurin coefficients of a function with the behavior of the function.  For example: P. Flajolet & A. Odlyzko,
``Singularity analysis of generating functions''
*Siam. J. Disc. Math.*  **3** (1990) 216-240

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Life will be simpler if we simplify the OGF using trigonometry.

Since $a \in [0,\frac12]$, if we define $s = 1-2a$ and $c = \sqrt{4a(1-a)}$, we will find $s, c \in [0,1]$.

Notice $c^2 + s^2 = 1$, we can pick a $\theta_0 \in [0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ such that $c = \cos(2\theta_0)$ and $s = \sin(2\theta_0)$.

For $0 \le cx \le c \le 1$, pick a $\theta \in [\theta_0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ such that $cx = \cos(2\theta)$.

We can rewrite the OGF as

$$\begin{align}{\rm OGF} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n x^n
&= \sqrt{1 - c^2 x - s\sqrt{1 - c^2x^2}}\\
&= \sqrt{1 - c\cos(2\theta) - s\sin(2\theta)}
= \sqrt{1 - \cos(2(\theta-\theta_0))}\\
&= \sqrt{2}\sin(\theta - \theta_0)
 = \sqrt{2}\left(\cos\theta_0\sin\theta - \sin\theta_0\cos\theta\right)\\
&= \cos\theta_0\sqrt{1-\cos(2\theta)} - \sin\theta_0\sqrt{1+\cos(2\theta)}\\
&= \cos\theta_0\sqrt{1-cx} - \sin\theta_0\sqrt{1+cx}
\end{align}
$$
Expand RHS by [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem), we find

$${\rm OGF} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty ((-1)^n \cos\theta_0 - \sin\theta_0)\binom{\frac12}{n} c^n x^\ell
\quad\text{ where }\quad
\binom{\frac12}{n} 
= \frac{1}{n!}\prod\limits_{\ell=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac12 - \ell\right)$$

Comparing coefficients of $x^n$ on both sides, we obtain a closed-form
expression for the sequence $f_n$:

$$f_n = ((-1)^n\cos\theta_0 - \sin\theta_0) \binom{\frac12}{n} c^n$$

To extract the leading asymptotic behavior of $f_n$, we rewrite  $\binom{\frac12}{n}$ using [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).
We have

$$\binom{\frac12}{n} 
= (-1)^n \frac{\Gamma(n-\frac12)}{\Gamma(-\frac12)\Gamma(n+1)}
= \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n-\frac12)}{\Gamma(n+1)}
$$

Notice for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, we have
$\displaystyle\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+\lambda)}{\Gamma(n)n^\lambda} = 1\;$. For large $n$, $\displaystyle\;\binom{\frac12}{n}$ behaves like $n^{-3/2}$.

As a result, the leading behavior of $f_n$ is given by following expression

$$f_n \approx -\frac{(4a(1-a))^{n/2}}{2\sqrt{\pi n^3}}\times 
\begin{cases} 
\cos\theta_0 - \sin\theta_0 = \sqrt{2a}, & n \text{ even }\\
\cos\theta_0 + \sin\theta_0 = \sqrt{2(1-a)}, & n \text{ odd }
\end{cases}
$$

**Update**

Let us switch to the side question how to extract the leading behavior of
$f_n' = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n f_k$.
The OGF of $f_n'$ is given by the formula.

$${\rm OGF}' = \sum_{k=0}^n f_n' x^n = \frac{\rm OFG}{1-x} =
\frac{\cos\theta_0\sqrt{1-cx} - \sin\theta_0\sqrt{1+cx}}{1-x}$$

When $a = 0$, OCF' is just constant $0$ and all $f_n' = 0$.

When $a = \frac12$, $c = 1$ and OCF' reduces to $\sqrt{1-x}$. It is easy to show $f_n'$ falls of like $n^{-1/2}$.

For the remaining cases, what happens depends on whether $a$ is far way or near $\frac12$.

When $a$ is far away from $\frac12$, everything is relatively simple.

The numerator of OCF' has two branch cuts ends at $\pm \frac1c$ and an zero at $x = 1$. This cancels out a potential pole from denominator. OGF' remains to be regular at $x = 1$ and the leading behavior of $f_n'$ is controlled by the behavior of OGF' at $\pm \frac1c$.

For $x$ sufficiently close to $\frac1c$, we have the expansion

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-cx}}{1-x} = -\frac{c}{1-c}\frac{\sqrt{1-cx}}{1 - \frac{(1-cx)}{1-c}}
= -\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\frac{c}{(1-c)^{\ell+1}} (1-cx)^{\ell+\frac12}
\tag{*1a}
$$

Notice for any $\alpha > 0$ and $|z| < 1$,

$$(1-z)^\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \binom{\alpha}{k} z^k
\quad\text{ and }\quad
(-1)^k\binom{\alpha}{k} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(-\alpha)k^{\alpha+1}}(1 + O(k^{-1}))\;$$

As far as leading behavior of $f_n'$ are concerned, we only need to keep the $\ell = 0$ term in $(*1a)$.
This is because contributions from the $\ell > 0$ terms have an extra factor $\frac{1}{((1-c)n)^\ell}$ attached to them. Since $a$ is far way from $\frac12$, $(1-c)$ will not be too small and we can safely ignore all of these.

Similar expansion is available when $x$ is sufficiently close to $-\frac1c$, we have

$$\frac{\sqrt{1+cx}}{1-x} = \frac{c}{1+c}\frac{\sqrt{1+cx}}{1 - \frac{1+cx}{1+c}}
= \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{c}{(1+c)^{\ell+1}} (1+cx)^{\ell+\frac12}
\tag{*1b}
$$

Once again, contribution from the $\ell > 0$ terms have an extra factor $\frac{1}{((1+c)n)^\ell}$ attached to them. We only need to keep the $\ell = 0$ term in $(*1b)$ in the extraction of leading behavior of $f_n'$.

At the end, we find when $a$ is far from $\frac12$, the leading behavior of $f_n'$ is of the form $O(n^{-3/2})$.

$$f_n' \approx \frac{c^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{\pi n^3}}\times \begin{cases}
\frac{\cos\theta_0}{1-c} + \frac{\sin\theta_0}{1+c}, & n \text{ even}\\
\frac{\cos\theta_0}{1-c} - \frac{\sin\theta_0}{1+c}, & n \text{ odd}\\
\end{cases}
$$

For the final case when $a$ is close to $\frac12$, the situation is more
complicated. I have no idea how to extract the leading behavior in a form depends on $a$ uniformly.

When $a \to \frac12^-$, $\frac{1}{1-c}\to \infty$. One no longer able to blindly ignore all the $\ell > 0$ terms in expansion of $(*1a)$.
One consequence of this is when $a \to \frac12^-$, above approximation fails to reproduce the $O(n^{-\frac12})$ behavior of $f_n'$ at $a = \frac12$.

If one want the leading behavior of $f_n'$ for $a$ near $\frac12$, one
should consider how to vary $a$ as one sends $n$ to infinity.

Comment: Thanks! Question: if we now consider $OGF' = OGF/(1-x)$. The coefficients of $1/(1-x)$ are $1$, so to get the coefficients of $OGF'$ we need to compute the convolution $1*f_n$, which is simply $\sum_{k=0}^nf_k$ where $f_k$ is what you got. For some reason when substituting I'm getting something weird. For example, if $a=1/2$ then $OGF' = 1/\sqrt(1-x)$ for which we know that $f_n' = {{-1/2}\choose{k}}(-1)^k$, but I can't get this one when using your $f_n$. Do have any idea what is going on? I don't want to open a new post because it seems too much related and simple addition.

Comment: @J.John The expression in last line is the leading behavior of $f_n$, it is consistent with the leading behavior of your $f_n'$. 
$$\begin{align}f_n' = (-1)^n \binom{-\frac12}{n} 
&= \frac{1}{n!}\prod_{\ell=0}^{n-1}(\frac12 + \ell) = \frac{\Gamma(n+\frac12)}{\Gamma(\frac12)\Gamma(n+1)}\\
&\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(1 - \int_1^n \frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x^3}}\right)\\
&\approx {\rm const.} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi n^3}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I see. The question is if I'm using your exact formula of $f_n$ (for any $a$), how can I extract the asymptotic behavior of $f_n'$.

Comment: Thanks for the update! It seems that if one only cares about the exponential behavior of $f_n'$ (and then polynomial decaying factors can be neglected) then $c^n$ is always the dominating term.

Comment: @J.John if one only want the exponential part, there is no need to calculate all of this. You essentially need to look at the distance $d$ to nearest signularity and then $f_n$ will fall off like $d^{-n}$ modulo some polynomial factor (if the signularity is a pole) or some factor that falls slower than exponential (when it is a branch cut). In your case, the potential pole at $x = 1$ get cancelled by a zero in numerator, so the nearest distance $d$ is $\frac1c$ and $f_n$ falls of like $c^n$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have some reference (book or something) for this argument (polynomial factor if the signularity is a pole or some factor that falls slower than exponential when it is a branch cut)?

Comment: @J.John It comes down to some formula by Cauchy. If $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n$ is analytic on and inside a contour $\gamma$ surrounding $0$, then 
$$f(\zeta) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-\zeta} dz
\quad\text{ for } \zeta \text{ inside }\gamma
\quad\implies\quad
f_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz 
$$
If $f$ is analytic over some disc $B(0,r+\epsilon)$ except at some pole $z_0$ with $|z_0| < r$, one can deform $\gamma$ to two circular contours  $C(z_0,\epsilon)$ and $C(0,r)$.

Comment: The contribution to $f_n$ from $C(z_0,\epsilon)$ falls off like $|z_0|^{-n}$ times a polynomial factor while the contribution from $C(0,r)$ will be bounded by $O(r^{-n})$. 

If $z_0$ is the end point of a branch cut instead, one can deform $\gamma$ to $C(0,r)$ together with something that wrap around the branch cut. The contribution from $C(0,r)$ again falls off like $r^{-n}$, the contribution from the branch cut will b $|z_0|^{-n}$ times something that depends on the detail of $f$ near $z_0$.

Comment: If you really want to learn how to extract the asymptotic behavior of $f_n$ from $f(z)$, look at the book "Analytic Combinatorics" by Flajolet and Sedgewick. In particular, Chapter IV is the one you are after. Flajolet have a [home page](http://ac.cs.princeton.edu/home/) for that book at princeton.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G_a(x):=\sqrt{1-4ab \cdot x+(a-b)\sqrt{1-4ab \cdot x^2}},\;$ where $b:=1-a$. Then we find also that
$G_a(x) = \sqrt{a/2}(f_a(x)+f_a(-x))-\sqrt{b/2}(f_a(x)-f_a(-x)),\;$
where $f_a(x):=\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{4ab}}.$

The coefficient of $x^n$ in $G_a(x)$ is asymptotic to
$\;-\sqrt{c_a(4ab)^n/(2n^3\pi)},\;$ where $c_a=a$ if $n$ is even, else $b$ if $n$ is odd.